# Ionic 3 currency formatting

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-pipe

I'm trying to format the currency with the following command

```
<h1>R$ {{item.valor | currency:"BRL":true:1.2 }}</h1>
```

but this error is shown

```
digitsinfo.match is not a function
```

How can I get the money in the correct format in Ionic 3?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the [CurrencyPipe docs](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe). The pipe expects following format:

```
{{ value_expression | currency [ : currencyCode [ : display [ : digitsInfo [ : locale ] ] ] ] }}
```

where `digitsInfo` is supposed to be

> **a string** which has a following format:
>   {minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}.

([Source](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe), emphasis is mine)

So formatting your `digitsInfo` as a string should fix your error:

```
<h1>R$ {{item.valor | currency:"BRL":true:"1.2" }}</h1>
```